# Increasing clarity of drawing on zoomed in bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-drawable

In my app I have a bitmap the size of the screen that I use for the canvas. I can zoom into this bitmap and draw onto the zoomed in bitmap. The problem is when I draw on this zoomed in bitmap the lines that I draw aren't very sharp and kind of blurry. I assume thats because a bitmap has only so many pixels so the closer you get to the pixels the worse the drawing is going to look.

I was wondering if there was a way to increase the pixels per inch of this bitmap that I am zooming in on. This way when I zoom and draw it can look sharper. Or are there other techniques out there to achieve this same goal.

Comment: have you tried a larger bitmap (and then using the scaled image)? Otherwise, you need to only zoom the bitmap, and draw the lines at a native resolution and not zoom the lines drawn as well.

Comment: I tried all of those but doesn't work. there just aren't enough pixels to go around. What I'm going to do is at a certain zoom scale load new bitmaps that can be drawn on. Thanks though